# Firebase Firestore addSnapshotListener() possibly causing "FragmentManager is already executing transactions" error

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I recently picked up on a project that I was working on a while back with updated dependencies, relating to this incident, I updated firestore's dependency (`com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore`) from 17.1.5 to the latest 18.2.0. Because of this update, now my app is suddenly throwing the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions

at a call of `addSnapshotListener()` in a Fragment's `onActivityCreated` method. (since the error is about `FragmentManager`, I thought this might be relevant)

Here's the specific code:

```
docRef.collection(COLLECTION_PATH).addSnapshotListener(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), (queryDocumentSnapshots, e) -> {
      //other stuff to do after detecting collection change
});
```

When I revert the dependency back to the old one, the error disappears. I'm guessing there's some sort of behavioral change in Firestore that broke my code, but I'm still not sure what exactly it is and how to fix it.

Here's the detail error stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureExecReady(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1657)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1717)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:228)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ListenerRegistrationImpl.lambda$onFragmentActivityStopCallOnce$1(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.2.0:190)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ListenerRegistrationImpl$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:6282)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ListenerRegistrationImpl.onFragmentActivityStopCallOnce(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.2.0:174)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ListenerRegistrationImpl.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.2.0:209)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.addSnapshotListenerInternal(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.2.0:917)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.addSnapshotListener(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.2.0:882)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.addSnapshotListener(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.2.0:823)
        ... [My app's call to addSnapshotListener] ...
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2565)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:907)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1235)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1301)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:710)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2071)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1861)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1816)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1693)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:560)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:148)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:743)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:815)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:403)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
```

*Update*: just updated to 19.0.0 and the error still exists.

Comment: Please add the code that you are using and indicate the line at which this error occurs.

Comment: I didn't think it would be necessary since 1. there's only one `addOnSnapshotLinstener` method and implementation should be the same expect for the specific document reference and collection path. 2. my code works without any changes if I revert to the old version of the Firestore dependency. Nevertheless, I edited the question to include my specific code if it helps.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Comment: For one month my project was really good, I haven't updated it in a week, but now it started to appear this error. I imagine the simple solution is implementing the `eventListener`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

remove getActivity() in your addSnapshotListener.
Handle the listener detachment with listener.remove on onPause().

```
    Query query = db.collection("cities");
ListenerRegistration registration = query.addSnapshotListener(
        new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            // ...
        });

// ...

// Stop listening to changes
registration.remove();
```

Comment: Why should I do that? Isn't the point of adding `getActivity()` to the listener to make it aware of the activity's life cycle?

Comment: I just tried removing the activity parameter from the listener, it worked, but would still just serve as a workaround since now I have to manually handle these listeners corresponding to my activity's life cycle. Do you know why that's the cause of the error and if there is a non-compromising fix?

Comment: yes, it was the purpose. But I don't know the reason behind this. As soon as I upgraded to new version, this error pops up. May be it was a bug.